# Accept a https connection with invalid certificate and validate the certificate before. Is it possible?

Tags: certificates, digital-signature

I will integrate with a new application on the next weeks. But something that was told to me by the partner team was very strange.

The partner ask us to pass one `.CSR` file with our company information: name, address, etc. After that they signed this file and send back to us. Until here, ok.

But after that, they said something like this:

> [...] we will setup our system to restrict the requests for the certificate. If someone try to make a request without the certificate, **our system will accept the connection without the certificate or with a incorrect certificate**, but the system will answer with a error for the sent requests.

As far as I know, if the certificate is invalid the https connection protocol will not accept the connection, no matter what. What I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

What your partner said is somewhat legit and ok from security perspective.

TLS is established between client HTTPS library and TLS server, not server app! Server app delegates TLS stuff to TLS server (Apache, IIS, dozens of them). Partner is planning to ignore certificate errors at TLS level (between client and web server). Instead, they apply certificate validation logic in web application. They simply check certificate details for every connection and if certificate fails, they will respond to client with error using client-server data protocol (SOAP, Web API Result, HTTP code, etc.).

In other words, there are two levels where certificate validation occurs: on TLS server and inside web application. They bypass all errors on first level and will handle them on app level.